# How to quote all items after comma-at them from a list

Tags: macros, common-lisp, quote

I want to expand `(foo a b c d e ...)` to ===> `(bar 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e ...)`

So far I only get this solution:

```
(defmacro foo (a1 &rest a2)
  `(bar ',a1 '(,@a2)))
```

But it results in:

`(foo a b c d)` ===> `(bar 'a '(b c d))`

which is not what I want.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'whatever` is shorthand for `(quote whatever)`. If you have a list of symbols like A, B, C, D, etc, and you want a list that contains the structure `(bar (quote a) (quote b) (quote c) ...)`, you can do something like this:

```
`(bar ,@(mapcar (lambda (symbol) (list 'quote symbol)) symbols))
```